# Read one column from multiple files in r

Tags: r, read.table

I have a carpet with multiple csv files (like 40) but I just want to read one column from them all, column 9, and assign that to a vector. Is there a way to do this without having to do it manually?

I think i saw a question similar to this one before, but I cannot find it anymore.

Thanks

Comment: Your title and description is confusing.  You want to extract a single row or column?.  If you want to get the column 9 from 40 files. we can read all the files in a list.  `files <- list.files(); lst <- lapply(files, read.table, header=TRUE, sep=''); lapply(lst, '[[', 9)` and `sapply(lst, '[[',9)` get the output in a matrix if the columns are of the same length in all the files

Comment: I got confused, sorry. I have 40 databes like this:    

  name   form   species   strand   function   site 

I just want the species info. However, as you mentioned, the databases does not have equal lenghts, that is why I was thinking in vectors, but is there a way to put them in a single data frame it would be awesome, thanks

Comment: You can read the files into a list as mentioned above (`lst`) and make the lengths equal.  i..e `lst1 <- lapply(lst, '[[', 9); data.frame(lapply(lst1, "lengths<-", max(lengths(lst1))))`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `colClasses` argument in `read.table` to limit the columns you want to read in.